# Ubuntu Linux server on network but can't see anything

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm running an Ubuntu server and I have plugged it into my local network.  I've modified the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to look like this:

```
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
  address 192.168.1.15
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

The interface comes up and shows the correct info.  The network cards at hardware level are blinking and showing traffic.  I can ping localhost.

I have run `tcpdump` on the interface and I'm seeing network traffic coming off card.  By all accounts the network is up and running and I don't see any errors.

However,  When I try to ping any computers on the network or try to ping back to this computer from other computers it is like it doesn't exist.  I've been working with linux servers for 10+ years and never seen anything like this.  Anyone have any ideas of what I might check?

ip a output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN   group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:0a:eb:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:0a:eb:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe0a:eb09/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100 
    link/none 
    inet 10.9.8.1 peer 10.9.8.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ifconfig output:

```
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:0a:eb:09  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe0a:eb09/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:179713 (179.7 KB)  TX bytes:128624 (128.6 KB) 
          Interrupt:17 Memory:feae0000-feb00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:590 (590.0 B)  TX bytes:590 (590.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.9.8.1  P-t-P:10.9.8.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: `tcpdump` seeing traffic going out means little. You must see expected traffic going in.

Comment: I don't see traffic going out, I see dns requests from router looking for computers on the network.

Comment: a router normally does not do DNS requests...

Comment: Please add the output of `iptables -L -n`, ping tests, relevant tcpdump traces, and the output of `ip a`, `ifconfig -a`, `ethtool eth3`

Comment: what is your default gateway? What is the output of `ip route`? Can you ping the default gateway? Are your interfaces up? What is the output of `ip a`?

Comment: iptables is not running.  firewall shut down.  pings just sit there and don't do anything unless it is localhost and it works fine.  I meant arp requests were being seen not dns.  using tcpdump -i eth3 -vv   After ctrl c I get

24 packets captured
267 received
237 dropped

Comment: It is difficult to get output of ip a and ifconfig due to having no network.  I'll get it shortly with usb drive

Comment: interfaces are up, firewalls down.  can't ping anything, including gateway.  Output of requests otw

Comment: route output
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth3 
10.9.8.0/24 via 10.9.8.2 dev tun0 
10.9.8.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.9.8.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.10

Comment: Added ifconfig and ip a to original post above.  I don't know how to format so it looks normal so sorry about it being all jumbled up.  Trying to figure that out now.

Comment: Move the cable from `eth2` (which isn't configured) to `eth3` (which is)? Just a thought :-)

Comment: thought about that already as you never know which is which but I have a cable plugged into both to be safe.  Originally I was trying one port at the time but now just have them both plugged into the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an active point-to-point VPN as can be seen by tun0; the VPN might be messing with local connectivity.

Many VPNs use what is know as full tunnel and mess with local connectivity for security reasons e.g. the "problems" you are describing are there by design, they are part of the intended security policy.

If you want to have local traffic, you have to turn off the VPN, but then you lose connectivity from whatever the other side that VPN is talking to.

Also the `tun` and dropped message packets on diagnostic data is a clue something fishy is going on. Seems that something/some software/a kernel module is dropped packets by design.

Comment: Good catch, however, I have removed the openvpn service completely with apt remove openvpn and rebooted the system and still do not have network connections.  In fact, I'm getting the exact same responses as before.  Just don't have the tun0 network device listed.

Comment: It is however a strong clue something is amiss /maybe  intencionally configured, and that we do not have enough data on this question to work with

Comment: Ok, will continue to research the VPN angle and see if maybe there is some configuration somewhere messing with me.  I'll post back if I find something there.  Thanks

Comment: Turns out this server had shorewall setup for the firewall.  Someone else set it up and I didn't realize they had the VPN there.  ufw wasn't being used so started looking for something else and found shorewall.  I turned it off and everything started working instantly.  So now need to figure out what is going on there and should be good.   Thanks again for pointing out the VPN as it was definitely the issue.

Comment: It was the tun and that dropped message in `tcpdump` to be more precise that were the clues. It had to be firewalling/a kernel module. Added to the answer to illustrate my reasoning.